# Call and Run doPost

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, http-status-code-500

Is it possible to call a doPost that exist in the same project. When I call the doPost in the same project I get a 200 response code but if I get someone else to run the same function they get a 500 response code. I am using the dev URL, executing the app as me, and anyone in my domain can access the app. Here is my [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1grloVkqa-4P3Gy1abiiPire_njTq_nkKx9t_qX8ZBaM/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function sendPost(){
  var sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  
  var webAppUrl = "<<my dev url>>"; //insert webapp URL of Dev or Exe script file
  
  var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  auth};
  var payload = {scriptName : 'updateDataV2', sheetURL : sheetURL};
  var options = { 
    method : 'post',
    headers : header,
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    payload : payload
  };
  
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl, options);
  Logger.log(resp.getResponseCode());
  
  var message = resp.getResponseCode() == 200 ? 'Database update complete' : 'There seems to be an issue. Please try again.';
  //if(resp.getResponseCode() == 200){resetFormulas();}
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message);
  
//Below 2 lines needed to setup access
//DriveApp.getFiles();
//DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}

function doPost(e){
  if(!e.parameters.scriptName){return ContentService.createTextOutput('A function name must be passed in a payload to run.');};
  
  Logger.log('parameters from caller ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var newText = this[e.parameters.scriptName](e); //This line runs the function being called with parameters
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(newText);
}
```

Here is the error message for the users.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//docs.google.com/favicon.ico">
      <title>Error</title>
      <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Product+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <style>/* Copyright 2020 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
         .goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png');background-size:116px 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:0.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:'Product Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png')}}
      </style>
      <style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}</style>
      <style type="text/css">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="outerContainer">
         <div id="innerContainer">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;">
               <div id="drive-logo"><a href="/"><span class="docs-drivelogo-img" title="Google logo"></span><span class="docs-drivelogo-text">&nbsp;Drive</span></a></div>
            </div>
            <p style="padding-top: 15px">Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.</p>
            <p>To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our <a href="https://support.google.com/docs/?hl=en&p=error_help" target="_blank">help center</a>.</p>
            <p><br><b>We're sorry for the inconvenience.</b><br><i>- The Google Docs Team</i></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <style>html {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}#outerContainer {margin: auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position: relative;}</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to do this? If they have access to the app, why not just execute the code?

Comment: @Diego I have a "database" sheet that I want to be able to better control who is and is not allowed to update that sheet. So what I am doing is getting the active user's email address, if their email is in a list then the sendPost function is fired and runs the update as me so that way I don't have to update the permissions on the database sheet. This sheet will potentially be shared with hundreds of users and I don't want just anyone updating it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I assume the users have write access to this spreadsheet file, which means they also have write access to the bound script. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, all users need to/will have write access to the spreadsheet.

Comment: *I am using the dev URL*. Only `exec` url respects permission configurations

Comment: @TheMaster I tried with exec and still got a code 500.

Comment: You can't rely on access controls that are written in a script editable by the users whose access you're trying to control. The users can easily overwrite those access controls.

Comment: @Diego I'm relying on my access controls to stop the people that don't know what they are doing. If someone is able to get past my simple controls then good for them.

Comment: Post the full retrieved data- not just 500

Comment: All I'm getting is 500. There is no other data. :/

Comment: `Logger.log(resp.getContentText());`

Comment: That is blank when I do that.

Comment: @TheMaster The person that I have helping me is off now so no testing till Monday. I will have him run it again and post the response here.

Comment: About `if I get someone else to run the same function they get a 500 response code.`, in your situation, how does the user run the script? I would like to confirm the method for executing the script by the user.

Comment: There is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/65045301/1393023

Comment: @Tanaike we both ran from a button and from the editor.

Comment: @contributorpw I'll make the changes from the other post on Monday when I get back to work and let you know if that works. Weird that someone else had the same issue on the same day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, about the settings of Web Apps, how about testing `"Execute the app as:" : Me` and `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous`, and then, `"Execute the app as:" : User accessing the web app` and `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone`? [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script) In this case, it supposes that the Google Spreadsheet are shared with the user. Please be careful this.

Comment: @TheMaster I have added the error message to the post along with a link to the sheet.

Comment: @Tanaike I made the changes you mentioned and still receive the error. 
Also after reading your reference what I am trying to do is user runs initial function, if their email is in the list then the request is sent to the doPost. The doPost is then to run as me (owner) since I will be the only to edit the protected sheets.

Comment: @contributorpw I reviewed and made the changes in the other post and still no luck.

Comment: Also post screenshot of script editor> view> executions> failed logs there. If what @contributorpw suggested in his answer is the reason, also try ```this[e.parameter.scriptName](e);//`s` removed```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

I debugged your code. And I saw the next line.

```
var newText = this[e.parameters.scriptName](e);
```

It's very interesting. And also it may get point to different things while you call a web app by different users.

Don't use `this` in that cases. Try override this to a dictionary or IIFE. In short you should be sure that all the code that your function wants to run has already been initialized. This will not work in the current context.

I copied the file then commented the next line

```
// var newText = this[e.parameters.scriptName](e);
```

then I re-published the app and it works fine now.

**Additional**

You need to publish the app for all auth users

[image]

or for all anonymous

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this did not solve my issue. I'm thinking it has something to do with the Authorization because it never reaches the doPost. Additionally, I have commented everything out in the doPost except the Logger.

Comment: @wjwelch1, check my project https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvzbrjLZoPGNIY56QEFEGX99T5raCXOmcANeLX6Fbfw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @wjwelch1, huh I can't reproduce the issue now. My project works for me fine for all my Gmail & Workspace accounts.

Comment: I just retried your copy and got a response code of 200. I just noticed that you have the execute as user accessing but I need the doPost to run as me/owner.

Comment: Hm... OK. You have to publish the web app for all even anonymous. The topic was updated.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer because it does solve my issue. 
However, this does not work on my work account since we do not have "...even anonymous". I did move the doPost to a new project in the same sheet and was able to get it to work.

Comment: @wjwelch1, do you use Google Workspace?

Comment: Yes, I believe my work uses Google Workspace.

Comment: @wjwelch1, unfortunately we can't. I also cannot imagine when such conditions might come. Most likely deployment in this mode is impossible.