# Google Script: Failed request and returned code 500

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, http-status-code-500

I'm experiencing an error called `code 500`. The script works fine if I'm using it in the owner account, but if I'm going to open the file as a user/editor, the `code 500` error shows. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sxGqNcmaTG8045AI6w1noIIYDcYtp5dfMVmaoYc-SQA/edit?usp=sharing) to the sample spreadsheet that I'm working on. I tried asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031013/google-sheet-exception-request-failed-for-https-script-google-com-returned?noredirect=1#comment114993751_65031013) but seems like it is a little complicated so I created a new single spreadsheet so that it can be easily identified the error.

[image: Code 500]

Here's the code

```
function doGet(e) {
  this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('It worked!');
}

function HideRows() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=script_HideRows&sheetName=" + activeSheet.getSheetName(), {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
// DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for the access token.
}

function showRows() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=script_showRows", {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
  Browser.msgBox(url + "?run=script_showRows");
}

var startRow = 6;
var colToCheck = 2;

// This script is the same with your "HideRows".
function script_HideRows() {
  var sheetNames = ["MS_Q1", "MS_Q2", "MS_Q3", "MS_Q4", "SUMMARY"];  // Please set the sheet names here. In this case, 4 sheets are used.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      if (sheetName == "SUMMARY") {  // When the sheet is "SUMMARY", the start row is changed.
        startRow = 7;
      }
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
    }
  });
}

// This script is the same with your "showRows".
function script_showRows() {
  // set up spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // get sheet
    var sh = sheets[i];

    // unhide columns
    var rCols = sh.getRange("1:1");
    sh.unhideColumn(rCols);

    // unhide rows
    var rRows = sh.getRange("A:A");
    sh.unhideRow(rRows);
  }
};

function shouldHideRow(ss, rowIndex, rowValue) {
  if (rowValue != '') return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex + 1, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, comment out this

```
// this [e.parameter.run] (e.parameter.sheetName || null);
```

Second, avoid this

```
const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

replace to

```
const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCD1234/exec';
```

Third, publish the web app for all user accessing every time you change code

[image]

The next code works for me fine

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('It worked!');
}

function HideRows() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url =
    'https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCD1234/exec';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url + '?run=script_HideRows&sheetName=' + activeSheet.getSheetName(),
    {
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    }
  );

  Browser.msgBox(response);
}
```

Comment: This part `const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCD1234/exec';` is the URL of the Web App, right?

Comment: Yep! This is your web app public endpoint. Not dev.

Comment: There is an error `Exception: Request failed for https://script.google.com returned code 401.`

Comment: Check twice. This forum is not intended for debugging someone else's code. I know for sure that I am getting a working result. The only difference is in those lines of code that I indicated.

Comment: I'm sorry! I'll figure this out. Thank you for the help!